Passing tasks arguments through to \item when using ExplSyntax with tasks to create a custom \item command
Using egreg's solution here: Using ExplSyntax with tasks to create a custom \item command - Making \item backwards compatible, I have created a custom command to sit on top of tasks. I am trying to pass the * command to \itemX to enable the 'wide' tasks option. Method in use seems to be flawed:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\NewTasksEnvironment{tasks_custom}[\item]

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\itemXSolutionBox}{m}{\par\textit{Solution:} ~ #1}

\NewDocumentCommand{\itemX}{s m O{}}{%
    #2 \IfBlankF{#3}{\itemXSolutionBox{#3}}
    }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytasks}
  {
    O{} % optional options
    D(){1} % number of columns
    +b % gather the contents
  }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #3 }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { \itemX } { \item \itemX }
  }
  {
    \my_task_make:nnV {#1} {#2} \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \my_task_make:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \begin{tasks_custom}[#1](#2) #3 \end{tasks_custom}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \my_task_make:nnn {nnV}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\section*{Example Task Lists}

\begin{mytasks}(3)
  \itemX{First item}[This is the solution]
  \item Second Item
  \itemX*{Third item}
  \itemX{Fourth item}
  \itemX{Fifth item}
  \itemX{Sixth item}
\end{mytasks}

\end{document}

Output:

Noting the extra albeit wide item generated at the top, but that is where 'First item' should be.
Would also be happy to use \itemX* instead of \item[wide] if possible.
Cannot seem to resolve this.

You get \item* \item \itemX[wide]{First item}[This is the solution] from the second replacement.

Unless there is a better solution, is it possible to then only replace:

\itemX[wide] with \item* \itemX
and
\itemX with \item \itemX

To achieve desired functionality?

I don't think you're going on the right route. Why not using \itemX*? And not mixing \itemX with \item, which makes for confusing syntax.

No problem, happy to, but currently if I use \itemX*{Third item} it just prints
c) *Third item
Rather than taking the wide version

you need to add the * possibility to the definition of \itemX and then test for it and respond accordingly. right now, you've not defined it to handle a star.

I've edited the code to offer the * possibility in the definition of \itemX, but the issue is that there is no 'item' within the \itemX definition to pass the * option to as that happens in the regex.
I tried (and failed) trying to run a conditional regex. I cannot seem to configure the regex pick up the #1 or * option from \itemX

Just figured out how to get around this by not running a second \item in the second replace. See answer below.

Managed to get a second regex to resolve the problem, although frankly don't understand why this works:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\NewTasksEnvironment{tasks_custom}[\item]

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\itemXSolutionBox}{m}{\par\textit{Solution:} ~ #1}

\NewDocumentCommand{\itemX}{s m O{}}{%
    #2 \IfBlankF{#3}{\itemXSolutionBox{#3}}
    }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytasks}
  {
    O{} % optional options
    D(){1} % number of columns
    +b % gather the contents
  }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #3 }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { \itemX } { \item \itemX }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { \itemX* } {* \itemX}
  }
  {
    \my_task_make:nnV {#1} {#2} \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \my_task_make:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \begin{tasks_custom}[#1](#2) #3 \end{tasks_custom}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \my_task_make:nnn {nnV}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\section*{Example Task Lists}

\begin{mytasks}(3)
  \itemX{First item}[This is the solution]
  \item Second Item
  \itemX{Third item}
  \itemX*{Fourth item}[Here is the solution]
  \itemX{Fifth item}
  \itemX{Sixth item}
\end{mytasks}

\end{document}



you've defined \itemX to take a * but you don't do anything with it. you want something like \IfValueTF{#1}{there's a star!}{sorry, no stars today}.
